$L_p$ norm estimate of a sum
Let $R>0$, and $(B_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ a collection of disjoint balls of radius R and let $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$   of the form
$$f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k X_{B_k}$$
for some sequence of  coefficients $a_n$ that depend on $R$.
For $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$ prove that $$||f||_q \leq C_n R^{n(1/p-1/q)}||f||_p$$
Where $C_n>0$ is a constant which depends only on the dimension $n$ (and, in particular, is
independent of $R$).
We can easily see that  $||f||_q^q=\sum_k|a_k|^qR^n$
I  solved the exercises for the case $R \geq1$. How can i do this for $R<1$?
Thank you in advance.

You are  using $n$ as the dimension of the Euclidean space and as an index for the terms of the summation.

It seems that the OP has a problem with the indices as he/she is using $n$ for both the dimensions of a presumably fixed Euclidean space and as an index for a sum.
Now, if the sets $B_m$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ are disjoint balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n$ fixed), then $\|f\|^q_q=\sum_m|a_m|^q R^n$.
For any $0<r<\infty$, notice that
$$\int|f|^r=\omega_n R^n\sum_m|a_m|^r$$
and so, $f\in L_r$ iff $\sum_m|a_m|^r<\infty$.
If $0<p<q$, then $0<p/q<1$. Recall that if $0<\alpha<1$, $(a+b)^\alpha\leq a^\alpha + b^\alpha$ for all $a,b\geq0$.
Then
\begin{align}
\|f\|^p_q&=\Big(\omega_nR^n\sum_m|a_m|^q\Big)^{p/q}\leq \omega^{p/q-1}_nR^{n\tfrac{p}{q}}R^{-n} \omega_n\sum_m|a_m|^pR^n=\omega^{p/q-1}_nR^{n\big(\tfrac{p}{q}-1 \big)}\|f\|^p_p
\end{align}
Consequently
$$
\|f\|_q\leq C_n(p,q)\, R^{n\big(\tfrac1q-\tfrac1p\big)}\|f\|_p
$$
For $R\geq1$, $R^{n\big(\tfrac1q-\tfrac1p\big)}$ is sharper than $R^{n\big(\tfrac1p-\tfrac1q\big)}$.
For $0<R<1$ the bound proposed by the OP does not hold in general. For $R>0$, suppose  $\mathcal{B}=\{B^R_m:m\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint balls of radius $R$. Then the balls $B^{R'}_m$ of radius $0<R'<R$ with same centers as those in $\mathcal{B}$ form also a pairwise disjoint sequence. Choose $a\in\ell_p\subset \ell_q$ for $0<p<q$ with $a\neq0$ and define
$$f^R=\sum_ma_m\mathbb{1}_{B_m}$$
Then
$$\frac{\|f^R\|_q}{\|f^R\|_p}=\omega^{1/q-1/p}R^{n(1/q-1/p)}\frac{\|a\|_q}{\|a\|_p}\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow0+}\infty
$$
If the bound in the OP were correct, then would have
$$\frac{\|f^R\|_q}{\|f^R\|_p}\xrightarrow{R\rightarrow0+}0$$


i need to prove the estimate with $(1/p-1/q)$ instead of $(1/q-1/p)$
